# Values are not added to List

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I am currently trying to use get the maximum value from a column in my datagridview, and use it in another part of the code. However, despite using the append function, I cannot get the values.

```cs
List<int> intValues = new List<int>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (!(row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
    {
        var a = row.Cells[$"donneesAVSS085DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
        if (!(a is DBNull))
        {
            intValues.Append(Convert.ToInt32(a));
            string k = (string)a;
            label17.Text = k;
        }
    }
}
int max = 0;
foreach (int value in intValues)
{
    if (value > max)
        max = value;
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: The [Enumerable.Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append) extension method **returns** and enumeration with the value appended to the source enumeration (the list in your case) but does not change the list.

Comment: Explains why I had issues getting my values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using`List.Add` instead of `List.Append` to add values to your list and then step through the debugger checking if the line where you are adding values to your list is reached. The debugger will show you if the conditional operators are returning true or false or if an object  is null so you know where to start tracing the issue.

Comment: I've come to realize that it may be an issue with the conversion. I'll still check the add thingy and keep you posted.

Comment: @Adam, by all means.

Comment: You sir are an absolute genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me (in around 4minutes)